# how can I use all scripts from custom folder like native shell commands in macOS

Tags: bash, macos, shell, zsh, iterm2

I am learning shell scripting, and I have written two scripts one that copies many files at once to a folder and if the folder does not exist it creates it, works like a charm! You may use it :D and the other one that moves them, I mean cuts and pastes :)

to copy:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ ! -e "$2" ]
then
    mkdir $2
fi

if [ "$3" ]; then
    cp -rn $1/*.$3 $2
    echo "Copying *.$3 done!"
else
    cp -rn $1/*.* $2
    echo 'Copying done!'
fi
```

to move:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ ! -e "$2" ]
then
    mkdir $2
fi

if [ $3 ]; then
    mv -i $1/*.$3 $2
    echo "Moving *.$3 done!"
else
    mv -i $1/*.* $2
    echo 'Moving done!'
fi
```

I would like to be able to use them like any other shell command (eg. ls, ping, cd...) everywhere in my system. How can I achieve that?
Thanks!

Comment: Put the directory that contains them in your `$PATH` environment variable.

Comment: BTW, `[ $3 ]` should be `[ "$3" ]`. Similarly, `mv -i $1/*.$3 $2` should be `mv -i "$1"/*."$3" "$2"` -- if you don't quote your expansions they're subject to word-splitting, so filenames or directories with spaces will misbehave badly. http://shellcheck.net/ will detect these issues automatically.

Comment: @Seven : Why is this tagged bash **and** zsh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to

1. Name each script file what you'd like to call it when you run it (**without the extension**), e.g. `copymany` and `movemany`
2. Place the `copymany` and `movemany` files in a folder, perhaps `~/bin`
3. Add the folder to your `$PATH` environment variable, e.g. `export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin`, in your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`

Comment: Questions that have been asked and answered many times before should be closed as duplicative rather than answered again. See the _Answer Well-Asked Questions_ section of [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @user17242583 : What's the point in emphasizing _without the extension_? If the OP wants to use file extensions, let him do so. We don't want to teach style questions here, do we?

Comment: @user17242583 : Also, in the way you defined `PATH`, the `~` would not be expanded to the HOME directory (neither in bash nor in zsh).

Comment: @user1934428 - There are concrete practical reasons for that "stylistic" choice; see the essay https://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful/ (which has long been linked by the #bash IRC channel factoid bot, being in line with consensus). Moreover, the OP asked how to be runnable "like ping" -- it's not named `ping.elf`. Someone coming from Windows might expect extensions to be ignored during search path evaluation but that's not the case here.

Comment: @user1934428: simply, I assumed the OP wanted to be able to run the command as though it were a normal command. Such a thing is very common among new developers, etc.